# Does moment duration() and humanize() handle small decimals?

Tags: momentjs

Why does this, which I expect to output something like '18 mins'...

```
const shouldBe18Mins = moment.duration(0.00003408923868091461, 'years').humanize()
console.log(`Should be 18 mins: ${shouldBe18Mins}`)
```

... instead output `a few seconds`?

By my arithmetic, 0.00003408923868091461 * 365 * 24 * 60 = 17.918 mins.